# Write random string into an element inline with text

Tags: html, arrays, string, random

I'm trying to write text chosen from a set of random strings inline with text in the html body. Here is my code so far:

Javascript

```
var textArray = [
    'STRING 1',
    'STRING 2',
    'STRING 3',
    'STRING 4',
    'STRING 5',
    'STRING 6'];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (textArray[randomNumber]);
```

HTML

```
<body>
TEXT <span id="output"></span> TEXT
</body>
```

It works in JSFiddle, but I get an error in browser "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null." What's wrong with this? Also, is there a more efficient way of doing this? Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxrclxst/TBRhS/).

Comment: Check if DOM is already loaded and if you have any typo in the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the JavaScript code is running before the DOM has been fully loaded, so there is no element with id `output` available.

Try running your JS code from inside the document.onload handler and it should work.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I missed the "onLoad" setting in JSFiddle. When I set it to "No Wrap - in <head>" the code breaks. Now, I'm not sure how to use the document.onload in conjunction with my current code. I'm very new to JS. What's the right syntax?

Comment: I wouldn't use onload, personally. Try putting your `<script>`'s at the very end of the body tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must add ready state and include jQuery.

```
$(function(){
   /*code here...*/
}
```

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/niezbor/X8NLF/)